# Preserve selection on reverse "Split into Lines" command

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

If you select few lines of text and press Ctrl-Shilf-L (or Menu > Selection > Split into Lines) you will see that there are multicursors on the end of each line.

Here is plugin which is trying to accomplish the similar task, but now the cursors should be located at the start of lines.

This plugin works, but I want slightly improve it - it should preserve selection, just like default Ctrl-Shift-L behaviour.

```
import sublime_plugin

class SplitIntoLinesReverseCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        self.view.run_command("split_selection_into_lines")
        # Seems to be redundant:
        # self.view.run_command("expand_selection", {"to": "line"})
        self.view.run_command("move", {"by": "characters", "forward": False})
        # Already tried this:
        # self.view.run_command("move", {"by": "characters", "forward": False, "extend": True})
```

Text for test:

```
foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo
bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar bar
baz baz baz baz baz baz baz baz baz baz baz baz baz baz baz baz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like this:

```python
import sublime_plugin

class SplitIntoLinesReverseCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        self.view.run_command("split_selection_into_lines")
        self.view.run_command("move", {"by": "characters", "forward": True})
        self.view.run_command("move_to", {"to": "bol", "extend": True})
```

The steps here are:

1. Use the existing command to split the selection into lines

   - This leaves every line selected with the cursor at the end of the line
2. Move the cursor forward one character

   - When there is selected text, moving the cursor forward or backward by characters shifts the caret to that end of the selection and removes the selection; this this leaves the carets at the ends of the lines and removes the selection.
3. Move the cursor to the beginning of the line, extending the selection

   - This puts the cursor at the position you want it to be in and puts the selection back.

There are other ways to do the same thing by manipulating the selections directly, but it's generally easier and faster to build on existing commands as is being done here.

---

The above solution will not work as expected if you have word wrapping enabled and any lines in the selection that are wrapping. This is because when a line is wrapped, the movement commands for jumping to the beginning and end of the line will jump to the logical (visual) end of the line the caret is on and not to the physical start and end of the line.

In order to work in a word wrapping situation you need to take that into account. Again, this would be possible by manually fiddling with the selections, but the easier way to is temporarily turn off word wrapping for the duration of the command so that the movements work as you expect:

```python
import sublime_plugin

class SplitIntoLinesReverseCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        # Save the state of word wrap and ensure that it's turned off
        word_wrap = self.view.settings().get("word_wrap", None)
        self.view.settings().set("word_wrap", False)

        self.view.run_command("split_selection_into_lines")
        self.view.run_command("move", {"by": "characters", "forward": True})
        self.view.run_command("move_to", {"to": "bol", "extend": True})

        # Replace the setting as long as it existed.
        if word_wrap is not None:
            self.view.settings().set("word_wrap", word_wrap)
```

Comment: Here is how it looks for me (word wrapping is enabled): https://imgur.com/a/ZNEpXRH. The problem is that second logical line (bar) selected only partially.

Comment: That's due to the word wrapping; when wrapping it turned on, jumping to the beginning of the line takes you to the start of the logical line and not the physical line. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Is there way to preserve carets on empty lines? Here is my attempt: https://jsfiddle.net/cd2mgnb6/. However, as you see, it doesn't works good.

Comment: @johnc.j.I'm not sure what you mean by empty carets; it's unclear what you're trying to achieve. It may be worth asking a separate question you can elaborate more on the input given and the output you expect.

Comment: Carets are the same as cursors. Select some text with empty lines (like shown here: https://jsfiddle.net/y39hk5Le/) and then press Ctrl-Shift-L. You will see that cursors (or carets) are located on empty lines as well as on text lines, of course. This is what I asked for.

Comment: I discovered `hardbol` and `hardeol` arguments for `move_to` command. With these arguments, it is possible to rewrite your code in a fewer lines, as well as achive the task I asked in the comments. Here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/oxbmqy0v/